# The right or standard way to play DOM in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have two divs, what I want to achieve is that, when I click `div left_1` then div `right_1` set `aria-selected=true` and `right_2` set `aria-selected=false`, the same behavior for `left_2` etc

```
+------------+      +-------------+ 
| div left_1 |      | div right_1 |
+------------+      +-------------+ 

+------------+      +-------------+ 
| div left_2 |      | div right_2 |
+------------+      +-------------+ 

...
```

DOM can be easily played by vanilla JavaScript, something like

```
document.getElementByClassName('left_1')[0].addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.getElementByClassName('right_1')[0].setAttribute('aria-selected',  true)
})
```

if need to make it more programming, we can do it `left_{number}` then change `right_{number}`'s attributes accordingly

I can do this way as well in react code, although reactjs uses virtual DOM, I found I am still able to use `document.getElementByClassName` or `querySelector` etc to select DIVs. However, I don't think that is a right/standard way to do.

My question is that, when we need to manipulate DOM quite often, do we just do multiple `Refs` like `this.left1 = React.createRef()` `ref={this.left1}`  `this.left2 = React.createRef()` `ref={this.left2}`... or there are some other ways to do. I am bit unclear on the DOM part.

Comment: Why you want to avoid virtual dom?

Comment: @geckos. No, I don't want to. If to achieve the goal, what is the best way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use react's `state` for this over `refs`, see here for [when to use refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs).

You could do something along the lines of:

```
handleClick = (e, position) => {
  this.setState({
    selected: position
  })
}

render () {
  <div name="left_1" onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, 1)}
       attribute={this.state.selected === 1}/>
  <div name="right_1" onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, 1)}
       attribute={this.state.selected === 1}/>
}
```

Of course you would need to add additional logic for *n* `div`'s. I can work on an example if you'd like.

**EDIT:** Here is a working example with *n* `div`'s:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { selected: 0 }

    handleClick = (e, position, number) => {
      this.setState({
        selected: {
          position: position,
          number: number
        }
      })
    }

    render() {
    
        const divNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        
        return (
          divNumbers.map(divNum => {
            const selected = this.state.selected.position === "left"
                             && this.state.selected.number === divNum ? "solid" : null
            return (
            <div>
              <div style={{float: "left", borderStyle: selected}} name={"left_" + divNum}
                   onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, "left", divNum)}>Left {divNum}</div>
              <div style={{float: "right", borderStyle: selected}} name={"right_" + divNum}
                   onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, "right", divNum)}>Right {divNum}</div>
              <br/><br/>
            </div>
          )})
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render((<App/>), document.getElementById('testing'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="testing"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example. Yes, I am seeking the right way to achieve the goal, perhaps no need to manipulate DOM? I need some ideas. Imagining I have 4 or 8 `left_{1,2,3,4...}` then how to achieve the goal efficiently.

Comment: I've added a working example with 8 div's. You can change the numbers by modifying the array. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to DOM element selection, using `refs` would be the proper way to go. You might also consider storing these positions in the `state` (depends from lots of things) and calculate the `styles/attributes/listeners` etc in the `render` method accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
If there are 8 DIVs for `left_{1,2,3,4...}` and 8 `right_{1,2,3,4...}` they all need to be in `state`, it is a bit manual job.